# Android, how to access static strings from the Main project into the library project?

Tags: java, android, encryption, library-project

I want to access the static strings present in the main project, from the library project.

**What I have :**

1. Library Project : Contains all the activities and functional code.
2. Main Project/s : Contains only the DB, String resources and drawables.

Both the projects are made by me. Everything is integrated and working perfectly.

**The Requirements :**

1. Every main project will contain an encrypted SQLite DB specific to that project.
2. I want somehow to store the decryption keys in the Main project and access them from decryption methods in the Library project.
3. The Decryption happens at run-time, so decrypting the Db while copying it from the package to the app's document folder is not an option.
4. I want the keys to be stored as static variables in a class so that they get compiled. So, storing the keys in String Resources is not an option.

The main requirement is that the Keys must get compiled, so that it becomes difficult to extract them from the apk.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I want to access the static strings present in the main project, from the library project. You can't do it.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti The main requirement is that the Strings must get compiled as they are decryption keys. If static strings cannot be accessed, then any other way would be fine, given that the strings get compiled.

Comment: Your library can't use resources of your MainProject. To do it, your library should have the main project as a dependency.

Comment: As already was mentioned, a library cannot access the main project, as it has no knowledge of it. That would actually defeat the purpose of the library concept in general. Besides, storing your keys as static variables within a class is inherently insecure. It's basically the same as using no encryption at all. So either consider not using encryption, or store the keys in a file encrypted with a PIN that is entered by the user upon app start. This pin can unlock the keys and be handed over into the library.